# Keyboard shortcut to apps menu

Tags: windows-8.1

That's all I want to know. I've googled this over and over to no avail. There's gotta be a keyboard shortcut to go directly into the apps menu -- what is it?

Comment: Windows 8.1 has a setting so that Start key/button automatically goes to the App menu. I'm assuming you want keyboard shortcuts to be able to go to either the App menu or the Start screen?

Comment: I want keyboard shortcuts to *both* menus. Not one or the other. I want to go to the start menu with the window key, and if my program is not there, I don't want to have to switch to my mouse and go all the way down to the lower-left of my very large screen to click a button to get into apps and look for it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're on the Start screen, try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.